# Reading CDATA value in comments of xml java

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, cdata

I've the below xml.

```
<add-item item-descriptor="sku" id="235957441">
    <set-property name="skuType"><![CDATA[NORMAL]]></set-property>
    <set-property name="isPartOfClearancePriceList"><![CDATA[false]]></set-property>
    <set-property name="size"><![CDATA[Single set]]></set-property>
    <!-- rdonly   <set-property name="prices"><![CDATA[then2price=-1.0,clearanceprice=-1.0,then1price=-1.0,extravaganzaprice=-1.0,wasprice=-1.0,nowprice=10.0]]></set-property>  -->
    <!-- rdonly  derived   <set-property name="dissectionName"><![CDATA[DUVETCOVERCOL2]]></set-property>  -->
  </add-item>
```

In the above xml, I've to read the values of `then2price`, `clearanceprice`, `then1price` of `prices` comment using java code.

I managed to read the comments but unable to read the `CDATA` of comments.

Java code :

```
        NodeList nl = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Element.COMMENT_NODE) {
                Comment comment = (Comment) nl.item(i);
                // System.out.println(comment.getNodeValue());
                Node child = nl.item(i);
                if(child instanceof CharacterData){
                    CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
                    System.out.println(cd.getNodeValue());
                }
            }
```

The above code is not printing the values inside CDATA, it is printing complete comment.

I just need `then2price=-1.0,clearanceprice=-1.0,then1price=-1.0,extravaganzaprice=-1.0,wasprice=-1.0,nowprice=10.0` in the output.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
String xmlStr = comment.getNodeValue();
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));

if (doc.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    System.out.println(doc.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
}
```

It will get you the data in CDATA as expected.

Note: And ofcourse you need to have xml-format for comments as well. Currently I do see you have 'rdonly' and 'rdonly  derived. Please remove them and call above method.